# Why are certain time values not plotting on this graph?

Tags: json, vega-lite, vega

Creating a scatter plot with vega points are only plotted up to the 11/12th of every month? I'm confused as I feel like everything should be working fine, however this clearly doesnt seem to be the case. Is this due to the data? or the choice of graph maybe? Feel as though there should be a solution but going through the documentation i can't find one

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "config": {"background": "#e6edf0"},
  "title": {
    "text": "Chart 1: Daily Cryptocurrency Returns",
    "subtitle": "Daily returns for six high marketcap cryptocurrencies source: Binance.com ",
    "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
    "subtitleFontSize": 10,
    "anchor": "start",
    "color": "black"
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andrewsnowdon/andrewsnowdon.github.io/main/Data_mega_final.csv",
    "format": {"type": "csv"}
  },
  "selection": {
    "Stockname": {
      "type": "single",
      "fields": ["Stockname"],
      "bind": {
        "input": "select",
        "options": [
          null,
          "DAX",
          "DOWJONES",
          "FTSE100",
          "NASDAQ",
          "S&P500"
          
        ],
        "name": "Pick an index: "
      }
    }
  },
  "transform": [
    {"filter": {"selection": "Stockname"}},
    {
      "filter": {
        "field": "Stockname",
        "oneOf": [
          "DAX",
          "DOWJONES",
          "FTSE100",
          "NASDAQ",
          "S&P500"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "height": 300,
  "width": 1000,
  "mark": {"type": "circle"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "title": "Date",
      "axis": {"grid": false}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Returns",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Daily Return (%)",
      "scale": {"domain": [-20, 20]},
      "axis": {"grid": false}
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "Stockname",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"scheme": "inferno"},
      "title": "Stockname",
      "legend": {"orient": "top-left", "fillColor": "aliceblue"}
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Stockname", "title": "Stockname", "type": "ordinal"},
      {"field": "Date", "title": "Date", "type": "temporal"},
      {"field": "Returns", "title": "Return (%)", "type": "quantitative"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source data appears to store dates using `DD/MM/YYYY` format, which Javascript date parsing assumes is `MM/DD/YYYY`. Because of this, when the day is larger than 12, the result is an invalid date.

You can fix this by declaring the correct date format in your specification:

```json
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andrewsnowdon/andrewsnowdon.github.io/main/Data_mega_final.csv",
    "format": {"type": "csv", "parse": {"Date": "date:'%d/%m/%Y'"}}
  },
```

See https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/data.html#format for more information.

Comment: Ah yes this is totally correct thank you. However now nothing seems to plot, it seems like when i parse the dates properly the system doesn't seem to recognise transform filter that i apply??

Comment: It all seems to work correctly when I try it. Comment threads are not a great place to go back and forth on things: perhaps you can open another question detailing exactly what you expect to see and how it's different than what you actually see?

Comment: Okay i Shall do that now

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo:p disregard what i said

Comment: Hello, Jake. I just discovered Altair and I am loving it. While browsing through your blog http://jakevdp.github.io/pages/about.html I found out the CV link is broken